# How do I detect if the charger is plugged in or unplugged using Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9

I want to detect when the charger is plugged and when it becomes unplugged. I want to write this using Swift. It would be great if someone share a code snippet for it, but if you can tell me what to use that would be nice.

Comment: The duplicate answer given above is in objectives not Swift.

Answer (score 10):

See [This doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html) for more info.

`Swift:`

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().setBatteryMonitoringEnabled(true)
if UIDevice.currentDevice().batteryState() == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging {
      NSLog("Device is charging.")
}
```